# Get method doesn't return defined optional value

Tags: python-3.x, methods

This is the code I am working with :

```
newResults = True
pages = 9

while newResults:    
    Request = f"{url}?key={API_Key}&ts={ts}&hash={hash}&project_id={project_id}&per_page= {per_page}&page={pages}&date_from={date_from}&date_to={date_to}"
    r = requests.get(Request)
    data = r.json()
    for id in data['tickets']:
        newResults = id.get('id', False)
    pages += 1
```

Once the code gets to the `newResults = id.get('id', False)` and the key doesn't exist, it breaks. Tried using an empty list, tried using a string. Tried printing newResult to see what's going on.It doesn't print the optional value.
The loop goes on forever.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: "it breaks" How?

Comment: The loop keeps going. 
newResults doesnt' become False

Comment: How many ``id``s are there in ``data['tickets']``? Do you want the loop to break if *any*, *all* or just *the last* ``id`` don't have an ``'id'``?

Comment: per_page is set to 100, on page 9 there is 100, on page 10 there is 28. 
I want to take all the ids before it breaks 
Basically, it should break on id 29 on page 10 as it doesn't exist.

Comment: well, if `data['tickets']` is an empty list then `newResults` will never be `False` -> infinite loop

Comment: data['tickets'] isn't an empty list. On page 10, there are 28 values in it. I want to iterate through those and turn newResults to false.

Comment: So, "Do you want the loop to break if any, all or just the last id don't have an 'id'?"

Comment: Just if the last id don't have an 'id'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Still no idea why .get() doesn't return False, but here is a way to do it.

```
newResults = True
pages = 9

while newResults :     
        ticketsRequest = f"{url}?key={API_Key}&ts={ts}&hash={hash}&project_id={project_id}&per_page={per_page}&page={pages}&date_from={date_from}&date_to={date_to}"
        r = requests.get(ticketsRequest)
        data = r.json()
        total = data['total']
        for id in data['tickets']:
            #stuff to do 
            result += 1
        pages += 1
        if result == total:
            print (project_id, total, result)
            break
```

Comment: Bit late to this one, but `id` is a built-in function in python (which is why it shows up in the same colour as `print` and a different colour from `newResults` or `pages` above), so is not a good choice of variable name. ticketID or something would avoid shadowing (i.e., overwriting within that function) the built-in function, and possibly some hard-to-spot problems. Same is true for `hash`. In the code above, it doesn't look like any initial value is set for the `result` counter.